# Converting a python data structure from one form to another

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[
{
    "medication_name": "Victoza", 
    "medication_id": 68, 
    "manufacturer_name": "Novo Nordisk", 
    "practice_id": 1, 
    "disease_id": 16, 
    "practice_state": "MA", 
    "disease_name": "Type II Diabetes", 
    "practice_name": "Cambridge Hospital Inc"
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Opsumit", 
    "medication_id": 39, 
    "manufacturer_name": "Actelion", 
    "practice_id": 1, 
    "disease_id": 12, 
    "practice_state": "MA", 
    "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension", 
    "practice_name": "Cambridge Hospital Inc"
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "ITCA-650", 
    "medication_id": 29, 
    "manufacturer_name": "Intarcia", 
    "practice_id": 1, 
    "disease_id": 16, 
    "practice_state": "MA", 
    "disease_name": "Type II Diabetes", 
    "practice_name": "Cambridge Hospital Inc"
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Flolan", 
    "medication_id": 22, 
    "manufacturer_name": "GlaxoSmithKline", 
    "practice_id": 1, 
    "disease_id": 12, 
    "practice_state": "CA", 
    "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension", 
    "practice_name": "Cambridge Hospital Inc"
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Adcirca", 
    "medication_id": 4, 
    "manufacturer_name": "United Therapeutics", 
    "practice_id": 1, 
    "disease_id": 12, 
    "practice_state": "CA", 
    "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension", 
    "practice_name": "Cambridge Hospital Inc"
}, 
.....
.....
.....
]
```

It is a pretty long list and has been truncated for readability.The list has quite a lot of repeated entries.What I would need is to find the unique values for each key and represented in the following data format:

```
{
medication : [ {medication_id : 1, medication_name: "Victoza"}, {medication_id :2, medication_name:"ITCA-650"},....]
practice   : [ {practice_id : 1, practice_name: "Cambridge"}, {practice_id : 2, practice_name: "Oxford"},...]
disease    : [ {disease_id: 1, disease_name: "Diabetes"}, {disease_id: 2, disease_name: "Obseity"},...]
manufacturer : [{name: "Cipla"}, {name: "Phizer"},...]
state : [{name:"MA"},{name:"CA"},...]
}
```

What would be the best way of doing it ?

Comment: why the negative vote..? atleast add a comment stating the reason for the down vote ?

Comment: Well you didn't say exactly how you want to reorganize it so we must guess from  your example output, but it looks like all you require is a simple for loop. Iterate over the list and put the keys you want into the new dict. Where did you get this data? This is a potentially expensive reorganization and it's possible you could have gotten it in the format you wanted in the first place.

Comment: the data is json output from a web service api..i just have access to the api end points and can only get the data in this format..also..the example output is exactly how the output is needed in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas, assuming `data` is a list of dictionaries as you showed

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
# In [38]: df
# Out[38]:
#    disease_id                     disease_name    manufacturer_name  medication_id medication_name  practice_id           practice_name practice_state
#    0          16                 Type II Diabetes         Novo Nordisk             68         Victoza            1  Cambridge Hospital Inc             MA
#    1          12  Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension             Actelion             39         Opsumit            1  Cambridge Hospital Inc             MA
#    2          16                 Type II Diabetes             Intarcia             29        ITCA-650            1  Cambridge Hospital Inc             MA
#    3          12  Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension      GlaxoSmithKline             22          Flolan            1  Cambridge Hospital Inc             CA
#    4          12  Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension  United Therapeutics              4         Adcirca            1  Cambridge Hospital Inc             CA

res = {}
res['medication'] = df[['medication_id', 'medication_name']].to_dict(orient='records')

# In [49]: res
# Out[49]:
# {
#     'medication': [
#         {'medication_id': 68, 'medication_name': 'Victoza'},
#         {'medication_id': 39, 'medication_name': 'Opsumit'},
#         {'medication_id': 29, 'medication_name': 'ITCA-650'},
#         {'medication_id': 22, 'medication_name': 'Flolan'},
#         {'medication_id': 4, 'medication_name': 'Adcirca'}]
# }
```

You get the idea, and do the rest the same way for 'practice', 'disease', and so on.

Comment: If you want only unique combinations (e.g. of medication_id and medication_name), do `df[['medication_id', 'medication_name']].drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records')` instead

Comment: let me give this a shot..will get back to you

Comment: @zyxue..works like a charm..one final thing..is it possible to arrange the medication list in alphabetical order by medication_name ?

Comment: Sure, something like `df[['medication_id', 'medication_name']].sort('medication_name').to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1):

```
final = {
    'medication': [],
    'practice': [],
    'disease': [],
    'manufacturer': [],
    'state': [],
}

for d in orig_list:
    medication = dict((k, d[k]) for k in ('medication_id', 'medication_name'))
    practice = dict((k, d[k]) for k in ('practice_id', 'practice_name'))
    disease = dict((k, d[k]) for k in ('disease_id', 'disease_name'))
    manufacturer = dict(name=d['manufacturer_name'])
    state = dict(name=d['practice_state'])

    if medication not in final['medication']: final['medication'].append(medication)
    if practice not in final['practice']: final['practice'].append(practice)
    if disease not in final['disease']: final['disease'].append(disease)
    if manufacturer not in final['manufacturer']: final['manufacturer'].append(manufacturer)
    if state not in final['state']: final['state'].append(state)
```

I only recommend this if you don't need to do this often.

Comment: @Amistad, try it now.